# Regarding Postgresql column length

Tags: postgresql, python

I am investigating an issue and the error log shows an error like this one:

> Error occurred (psycopg2.DataError) value too long for type character varying(8192)

I could not find what causes the issue. Upon searching I got to know it's an issue with the length. I tried to search the column definition and got as below.

```
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
run_id = Column(String)
timestamp = Column(String)
machine_id = Column(String)
events = Column(String)
event_details = Column(String)
```

I didn't see any where the length is declared so got confused with this. What might be the issue? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Check the `CREATE TABLE` statements that were generated. For one of the columns, a limit of 8192 characters was defined

Comment: I am using 
        postgresql = PostgresqlAlchemy()
        postgresql.create_session()
and then inserting
        postgresql.session.add_all(data)

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. Check the actual table as it was create **in the database** (e.g. in `psql` do a `\d your_table_name`). You need to find out what your obfuscation layer (psycopg2) created.

Comment: Yes, thanks will check it. :)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20974/should-i-add-an-arbitrary-length-limit-to-varchar-columns/21496#21496